# Will $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] return subdomain folder when the code is inside this folder?

Tags: php

I've searched but couldn't find any clear answer to that question.
Will `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` always returns the server root?

I mean it does say `DOCUMENT_ROOT`, not `SERVER_ROOT` or something.

Excuse me if it's a dummy question, I am a dummy...

Comment: From the docs `The document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.` So if you have each subdomain using its own vhost (for example) which has its own document root, it will give you the one from the relevant vhost config.

Comment: You can easily test this with a few lines of code.

Comment: @Jonnix Hay, sorry for my lack of knowledge. Is the "server configuration file" '.htaccess' file?

Comment: No, it's the the vhost configuration files. .htaccess is too late.

Comment: @Jonnix Alright, I think i got it know i've researched about the vhost configuration file and things are a little bit clearer now, Thanks! One thing i didn't understand though, In your first reply you've said i can have multiple vhosts files?

Comment: Yes, a single web server can handle multiple domains and sub-domains (i.e. multiple website / applications). Each domain you want to handle can (doesn't have to) have its own vhost configuration.

Comment: @Jonnix Awesome, Thank you very much! And again I'm sorry for taking your time on a topic that seems already clear for everyone else. I just couldn't figure it out before.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the value of `doc_root` configuration setting as described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.doc-root), or document root set in web server configuration.

Comment: Hay, I couldn't understand a thing from that. But that's alright @Jonnix helped me figure it out. Thanks.